# Obtener el usuario de Windows donde se está ejecutando el navegador C#

Tags: c#

Requiero obtener la cuenta de Usuario con la que inicie sesión, cuando se abre la url del sitio que está publicado en un IIS del Windows Server, estaba utilizando `Environment.UserName`, cuando es localhost, si me obtiene el nombre de mi usuario, pero cuando ya lo ejecuto sobre la url del servidor me obtiene el usuario del servidor, alguien sabe como puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Si te refieres al usuario de windows, debes activar el modo de autenticación de tu aplicacion a `Windows` únicamente en el IIS.

Comment: SOLUCIONADO. En efecto, la solución fue activar la autenticación de Windows en la aplicación del IIS. En caso de que la opción no aparezca, se deben instalar los Rules and Features para que la opción se encuentre disponible. Gracias por su comentarios.